# Conflicting declaration

Tags: c++, typedef, conflict, size-t

I have a typedef defined in my code as

```
typdef unsigned int size_t;
```

it is conflicting with stddef's

```
typedef __SIZE_TYPE__ size_t;
```

I'm unsure how to get around this but would still like to keep size_t in my code.

Comment: Pick a different name or put it in a namespace.

Comment: Why not just use the one in `stddef`?

Comment: Pick a different name and you'll be fine.

Comment: I have an idea, why don't you pick a different name?

Comment: It might help to clarify your thinking if you phrased your post in the form of a question. Do you have a specific question, or are you merely stating facts?

Comment: I chose to go with the namespace answer and it solved the issue. thanks for all the assistance. :)

Comment: Identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved for POSIX. Pick a different name.

Comment: There's no good way to break [the rules](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html)

Comment: You really need to pick a different name.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

<del>Two</del> Three options:

1) Pick a different name, I think you already got that.

2) Use a `namespace`:

```
namespace X
{
   typedef long size_t;
}
```

and the type as

```
X::size_t x;
```

3) Ugly, guaranteed to get you fired, and me downvoted:

```
typedef unsigned int my_size_t;
#define size_t my_size_t
```

Comment: AHH. I like your answer best. Problem is this is for a project and the size_t typedef name in my code is something I cannot change. Thanks!

Comment: hahaha alrighty. the namespace answer still wins for me but thanks again! :)

Comment: I love your 1,2,3. It's the good, the bad, and `#define _UGLY`.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a bad idea to try to redefine a type that's in one of the standard headers. What are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you want to use the standard size_t definition?

Comment: This should be a comment saying "Pick a different name." :P

Comment: LOL, you're right, that seems to be the direction folks have taken.

Comment: I would if I could but this is for a project that I cannot change that name. Thanks for the suggestions :)

Comment: @user1496542 Sounds like an artificial requirement, especially since the name is conflicting with a type declared in the standard headers... which is why identifiers ending in `_t` are reserved.